# how to use loops to parse csv text with the tkinter library in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, tkinter

I created a loop to search a CSV file and return a row with a specified keyword. When the else function is hastagged out, the loop works fine.

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box

master = Tk()

label1 = Label(master, text = 'User_ID', relief = 'groove', width = 40)
label2 = Label(master, text = 'User_Info', relief = 'groove', width = 40, height = 5)

e1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 40)
e2 = Text(master, relief = 'groove', width = 40, height = 5, borderwidth = 2)

def enter():
    csvfile = open('stack_example.csv', 'r')
    read = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in read:
        if str(e1.get()) in row:
            e2.insert("1.0", row, 'r')
            #break
        #else:
            #box.showinfo('Search Result','Not Found')
            #master.mainloop()


button3 = Button(master, text = 'Retrieve File', relief = 'groove', width = 25, command=enter)

label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )

e1.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
e2.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )

button3.grid( row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
```

However, when the else function is part of the code, the loop skips right to the else command and ignores the if command. The output produced above is an insertion of the row with the keyword from the csv file to a text widget. But, the output below is a display box. (with the same entry keyword, that is in the csv file)

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box

master = Tk()

label1 = Label(master, text = 'User_ID', relief = 'groove', width = 40)
label2 = Label(master, text = 'User_Info', relief = 'groove', width = 40, height = 5)

e1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 40)
e2 = Text(master, relief = 'groove', width = 40, height = 5, borderwidth = 2)

def enter():
    csvfile = open('stack_example.csv', 'r')
    read = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in read:
        if str(e1.get()) in row:
            e2.insert("1.0", row, 'r')
            #break
        else:
            box.showinfo('Search Result','Not Found')
            master.mainloop()


button3 = Button(master, text = 'Retrieve File', relief = 'groove', width = 25, command=enter)

label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )

e1.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
e2.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )

button3.grid( row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
```

My understanding is that only if an if statement is false does the else command execute. However, the else statement seems to be overriding the if statement with this code. I am unsure of how to write a loop that will function so that:

1. if the keyword is in the csvfile
2. then the row with the keyword is inserted to a blank widget
3. if the keyword is not in the csvfile
4. then a box with text 'Not Found' is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `else` condition is observed at least once in the `for` loop, the text will change. So, your `if` statement code is likely still being evaluated, but you are also observing the `else` behavior in the same loop. Try this:

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box

master = Tk()

label1 = Label(master, text = 'User_ID', relief = 'groove', width = 40)
label2 = Label(master, text = 'User_Info', relief = 'groove', width = 40, height = 5)

e1 = Entry(master, relief = 'groove', width = 40)
e2 = Text(master, relief = 'groove', width = 40, height = 5, borderwidth = 2)

def enter():
    csvfile = open('stack_example.csv', 'r')
    read = csv.reader(csvfile)
    contains_keyword = False
    for row in read:
        if str(e1.get()) in row:
            contains_keyword = True
            break
    if contains_keyword:
        e2.insert("1.0", row, 'r')
    else:
        box.showinfo('Search Result','Not Found')
        master.mainloop()


button3 = Button(master, text = 'Retrieve File', relief = 'groove', width = 25, command=enter)

label1.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10 )

e1.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
e2.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10 )

button3.grid( row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been working on this for hours!!